# VM instance is missing from the console google cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

[To see image click here, about this missing server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMXGH.png)

It was working fine those days and now stopped suddenly, and don't return to work

Comment: This image only shows one VM which was created last November. What is the problem you are having with it?

Comment: It's not giving me the Extern IP and today I can't access this VM

Comment: You didn't activate your free $300 credit either? Maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Good Idea, I will see, who is paying is my client, I will check the bills.